# here used Object Input Stream to insert data of object into data base

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

i have Drugbean object which has to be inserted to data base  i used object input stream in order get the object from another class when i insert the data of the object into data base i get java.io.EOFException

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int flag=0;
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DrugModel drugBean = new DrugModel();
        List<DrugModel> itemFromClient = new ArrayList<DrugModel>();
        List<String> itemToClient = new ArrayList<String>();    
        try {           
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());          
            while((drugBean = (DrugModel) inputStream.readObject())!=null){             
                flag = MakeConnection.insertDrugRecord(drugBean);                           
            }                           
            inputStream.close();                        
            if (flag == 1) {
                itemToClient.add("true");
                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeObject(itemToClient);
            } else {
                itemToClient.add("false");
                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeObject(itemToClient);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

cosole.error

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.medeil_plus.SyncDrugTable.doPost(SyncDrugTable.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: could you post complete exception stacktrace ?

Comment: pls see the error above    @Ravi

Comment: Are you expecting the input stream to contain multiple objects? What is sending the requests? Are you sure the sending program correctly sets up the corresponding `ObjectOutputStream` and writes the expected objects to it?  Without seeing the sending code we cannot possibly help you.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am most surprised to find that that is a blatant misquotation. What it *actually* says is 'Any attempt to read object data which exceeds the boundaries of the *custom* data written by the corresponding *`writeObject`* method'. My emphasis. There is no 'custom data' in evidence here (which comes from custom `writeObject()` methods inside the `Serializable` object). There is nothing there about `readObject()` returning null at EOS either. See the duplicate, and there are many others. If you don't believe it, please try it before you debate this further with me.

Comment: I'm not debating, just really curious why `EOFException` is not mentioned for `readObject()` at all.  Since that is the way EOF is communicated, you'd think it would be mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`EOFException` when calling `readObject()` is normal. It happens when you reach end of stream.

Your mistake is in assuming it returns null at end of stream. It doesn't. It can return a null any time you wrote a null.

So your read loop should be `while (true)`, with an explicit catch for `EOFException` to exit it.

Comment: Just for my clarification, are you saying making mentioned change will resolve the issue ? even `readObject` doesn't have anything ?

Comment: Of course I'm saying that. I posted this as an answer. I don't know what you mean by '`readObject()` doesn't have anything'.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you meant loop might not have executed because `inputStream.readObject()` might have null ?

Comment: That is *exactly the opposite* of what it says in my answer. I can only suggest you read it again. I'm not going to just repeat myself here.